# Show that the function $f=0 $ in $[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Let $f$ be a differentiable function (infinitely differentiable) defined on $[0,1]$ and let: $f(0)=f(1)=0$. Now, if $f''(x)=e^xf(x) $ then I need to show that $f=0$ on the domain

I was thinking that showing $f'(x) \ge 0$ will let me conclude that $f=0$ on the domain.

How do I show that $f'(x) \ge 0$?